# Highlight ListView row based on database value

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to highlight a ListView row based on a value pulled from the data set that is populating the ListView.  As shown in the code below, I know how to modify a textview based on a database value via a view binder.  Is there is a way to update the row from the view binder?  As far as I know, I can only update text fields from the view binder, not the parent row attributes.

I'm currently using a SimpleCursorAdapter but suspect I need to create a custom adapter of some type.  However, once I'm in the custom adapter, I cannot access the db cursor to read a field to determine whether or not to highlight the row, can I?

Just to clarify, I'm not trying to highlight the row when it is selected; I know how to do that.  Nor am I trying to highlight just a textview - I'm trying to highlight the entire listView row (or at least a LinearLayout in my R.layout.stream XML file.

I have a boolean value in the database record that indicates whether or not to highlight that row.   Thanks for any input you can give!

Here is a portion of my main activity:

```
    cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, DbHelper.C_TIMESTAMP + " DESC", null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.stream, cursor, FROM, TO);

    adapter.setViewBinder(VIEW_BINDER);

    listStream.setAdapter(adapter); 
 ...
```

And here is a portion of the view binder:

```
 static final ViewBinder VIEW_BINDER = new ViewBinder() {

    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.textTimestamp) {


            String postDate = cursor.getString(columnIndex);    

            ((TextView) view).setText(tHandler.getRelativeLocalTime(view.getContext(),postDate));

            return true;
 ...
```

The relevant part of the activity XML layout file:

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listStream"
        android:background="@color/lightGreen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/streamHeader">           
    </ListView>
```

Comment: have you got the solution for this?